# Inkscape : how to ensure inkscape starts with "100%" rather than "35%" which seems to be the default

Tags: inkscape

Everytime i open

```
 Inkscape
```

the magnification is set to

```
 35%
```

i need it to start with

```
100%
```

so i do not end up designing something wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the default template. The path should be: `YourPath\Inkscape\share\templates\default.svg`

The file should contain values such as:

```
 id="base"
 pagecolor="#ffffff"
 bordercolor="#666666"
 borderopacity="1.0"
 inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
 inkscape:pageshadow="2"
 inkscape:zoom="0.35"
 ...
```

Modify "0.35" to whatever value you would like :)

Note: I believe each document contains its own local values that supersede the default values, so changing the default may only affect *new* documents.

Comment: on a linux system, the default.svg file will be somewhere like `/usr/share/inkscape/templates/`